# How can I populate a listbox with a sql query more efficiently?

Tags: c#, sql-server, performance, listbox

I have a ListBox that I am populating with a sql server stored procedure that returns about 5000 rows.  My stored procedure looks like this.

```
SELECT UserID,LanID
FROM User
ORDER BY LanID
```

Right now I create a DataTable from this procedure, and use that DataTable as the ListBoxes Data Source.

```
    public DataTable getAllUsers(string environment)
    {
        List<Criteria> userList = new List<Criteria>();
        using (SqlConnection sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(GetConnectionString(environment)))
        {
            sqlConnection.Open();
            using (SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter("usp_GetUser", sqlConnection))
            {
                var dataTable = new DataTable();
                adapter.Fill(dataTable);
                return dataTable;
            }

        }
    }
```

and this is how I call this method

```
 private void setUsersListBox()
    {
        DataTable dtOfUsers = groupDetailDataAccess.getAllUsers("Development");
        UsersListBox.DataSource = dtOfUsers;
        UsersListBox.DataBind();
    }
```

The problem with all of this is once the page loads I can do what I need to do on the web page for about 10 seconds and then it freezes up for about 20 seconds. After that it works fine until the page is refreshed or reloaded. I narrowed it down to this listbox/query that is causing the problem.

Is there a way that I can make this more efficient to increase the performance?

Comment: Do you really need 5000 rows in your list box? I think that would make the box clunky and hard to use. Is there a better way of allowing the user to choose the data here?

Comment: Could you run the query on a separate thread?

Comment: @BeanFrog I mostly wanted a list box to keep it consistent with the rest of the page. I would need the user to be able to select multiple users so I thought the list box would be the best option

Comment: How long does the procedure take to execute? I agree though that a listbox with 5,000 items is rather cumbersome for a user.

Comment: You want them to choose out of a list of 5000?

Answer (score 1):

Every logic action ( that takes time to process ) should be on a separate thread so it wont lock the main UI thread .